# Mudblazor Drag and Drop - Cannot drag to empty dropzone

Tags: drag-and-drop, blazor, .net-7.0, mudblazor

I have used the code on this page:
https://mudblazor.com/components/dropzone#transfer-items-between-drop-zones-drop-item-selector
to try out the Drag and Drop functionality, specifically the section **"Transfer Items Between Drop Zones"**.  It works fine.  However, I now need to customise it for my own needs.  The issue I am having is that I have created two dropzones, but when one of them becomes empty, I cannot drag items back on to it.  Here is my single page of code:

```
@page "/dragdrop"

<h3>Drag And Drop Demo</h3>

<MudDropContainer T="DropItem" Items="_items" ItemsSelector="@((item,dropzone) => item.Selector == dropzone)" ItemDropped="ItemUpdated" Class="d-flex flex-wrap flex-grow-1">
    <ChildContent>
        @for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
        {
            var dropzone = i.ToString();
            <MudPaper Class="ma-4 flex-grow-1">
                <MudList Clickable="true" Class="d-flex flex-column mud-height-full">
                    <MudListSubheader>Drop Zone @dropzone</MudListSubheader>
                    <MudDropZone T="DropItem" Identifier="@dropzone" Class="flex-grow-1" />
                </MudList>
            </MudPaper>
        }
    </ChildContent>
    <ItemRenderer>
        <MudListItem Text="@context.Name" />
    </ItemRenderer>
</MudDropContainer>

<MudDropContainer T="Vehicle" Items="_vehicles" ItemsSelector="@((item,dz) => item.Selector == dz)" ItemDropped="VehicleUpdated" Class="d-flex flex-wrap flex-grow-1">
    <ChildContent>
        <MudGrid>
            <MudItem xl="4">
                <MudPaper Class="ma-4 flex-grow-1">
                    <MudList Clickable="true" Class="d-flex flex-column mud-height-full">
                        <MudListSubheader>Vehicle Bank</MudListSubheader>
                        <MudDropZone T="Vehicle" Identifier="VehicleBank" Class="flex-grow-1" />
                    </MudList>
                </MudPaper>
            </MudItem>
            <MudItem xl="4">
                <MudPaper Class="ma-4 flex-grow-1">
                    <MudList Clickable="true" Class="d-flex flex-column mud-height-full">
                        <MudListSubheader>Assigned Vehicles</MudListSubheader>
                        <MudDropZone T="Vehicle" Identifier="AssignedVehicles" Class="flex-grow-1" />
                    </MudList>
                </MudPaper>
            </MudItem>
        </MudGrid>
    </ChildContent>
    <ItemRenderer>
        <MudListItem Text="@context.VehicleReg" />
    </ItemRenderer>
</MudDropContainer>

@code {
    private void ItemUpdated(MudItemDropInfo<DropItem> dropItem)
    {
        dropItem.Item.Selector = dropItem.DropzoneIdentifier;
    }

    private List<DropItem> _items = new()
    {
        new DropItem(){ Name = "Item 1", Selector = "1" },
        new DropItem(){ Name = "Item 2", Selector = "1" },
        new DropItem(){ Name = "Item 3", Selector = "1" },
        new DropItem(){ Name = "Item 4", Selector = "2" },
        new DropItem(){ Name = "Item 5", Selector = "2" },
    };

    public class DropItem
    {
        public string Name { get; init; }
        public string Selector { get; set; }
    }

    private void VehicleUpdated(MudItemDropInfo<Vehicle> dropVehicle)
    {
        dropVehicle.Item.Selector = dropVehicle.DropzoneIdentifier;
    }

    public class Vehicle
    {
        public string VehicleReg { get; init; }
        public string Selector { get; set; }
    }

    public List<Vehicle> _vehicles = new()
    {
        new Vehicle(){VehicleReg = "EF66FUG", Selector = "AssignedVehicles"},
        new Vehicle(){VehicleReg = "PA11LDR", Selector = "VehicleBank"},
        new Vehicle(){VehicleReg = "MY66XXY", Selector = "VehicleBank"}
    };
}
```

If my starting position is as per the code (i.e. I have at least one vehicle in each dropzone), I can drag from my VehicleBank dropzone to the AssignedVehicles dropzone (or vice-versa), but as soon as I empty one of them, I can no longer drag anything back to it.  The top half of the code is directly from the mudblazor page and works perfectly.  I cannot see why the top part works (i.e. you can drag to an empty zone) but the bottom half does not.

Any guidance gratefully received.

Answer (score 2):

OK, so after hours of Googling before posting the question, my next search revealed this gem:
https://github.com/Postlagerkarte/blazor-dragdrop/issues/132
so I replaced

```
<MudDropZone T="Vehicle" Identifier="VehicleBank" Class="flex-grow-1" />
```

with this

```
<MudDropZone T="Vehicle" Identifier="VehicleBank" Class="flex-grow-1" Style="@($"min-height:50px")" />
```

And now it works perfectly as even when empty the dropzone has a surface to drop something on.  Still doesn't explain why the first bit works and the second doesn't though.

Comment: This was driving me bonkers. It still, to this day has an empty height if the column is empty. This fixed it.